# how to stack NDVI band from sentinel 2 and sentinel 2 bands to improve vegetation classification in qgis

Tags: qgis

I am trying to perform vegetation classification using sentinel 2 image, and I understand that I can also apply ndvi in order to improve my classification. now I have created the ndvi from the sentinel 2 and I have stacked it and the resulting raster image is black. I need to know if it's supposed to be like that or is there anything that I need to do. i am using qgis

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question has been asked over 2 years ago, I still want to answer as it may be helpful to someone asking the same question - and not to mention, I ran into similar problems!

So, firstly make sure that you have indeed used the correct bands - in sentinel 2 dataset these are the B8 - which is the near infrared band - and the B4 - which is the red light spectrum band. If you are following the GEE tutorials watch out as they give examples with the LANDSAT rather than Sentinel data and hence use different bands!

Secondly, take a careful look at your NDVI implementation (in case you did not use the in-built method: """var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI');"""

Lastly, you need to define the visual parameters for the NDVI in the correct way. As it was already stated by @Walshe_d in the answer above, make sure that the min and max parameters are set to -1 and 1 respectively. Also, define the palette. Something along these lines should work:
"""var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};"""

Hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say as you don't specify what is in your image but I would check the values. If the values present are between -1 and +1 try changing the Symbology in properties in QGIS. Change the color gradient min to -1 and the max to +1 and see if that changes the colour.

If your values are not between -1 and +1 then you have not calculated NDVI correctly.